# How to get the desired from the SQL Server Query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

The below query is my query I have written to generate Weekly Status Report.

In that the Upper parts of the query above 'Union' gives the Overall Status of each BU Name and Product Name.

The other parts of the query gives the detailed analysis of the Overall Status, It gives the results of each project and name of each engineer working on it.

The below query gives me complete results in the database from the beginning till date.

But when the user chooses the date, I want results only from that date till date. Because it is a weekly report.

I want few more column data in the Results like number of parts completed last week and number of parts completed by each engineer this week.

And whenever I add some thing in the code, I get a error to add the column name in group by and I am not getting the desired results if I add it.

1. From the given from date - 7 days count of parts which are completed.
2. And by including the above things, the overall status number should match with individual ones
   like (+ of all individual = Overall)

---

```
 select BU.bu_desc as [BU], prod.Product_Desc as [Product Name], NULL as [SC-ID], 
 'OVERALL PROJECT STATUS' as [Project Name],
 NULL as [Requestor], NULL as [Request Date],

 case
 when BU.bu_desc in ('DSM','Synexis','ALD') then 'GW'
 when BU.bu_desc in ('Etch','SRP','FEP') then 'MS'
 when BU.bu_desc in ('CMP','MDP') then 'RS'
 else 'PT'
 end as [PM],

 NULL as [SCE],
 (count(parts.part_id_num)-count(parts.cancelled_date)) as [Total Parts Requested],
 '' as [No. Of Parts Completed Last Week],
 '' as [No. Of Parts Completed This Week],
 count(parts.analysis_Complete_date) as [Total No.Of Parts Completed], 

 case 
 when (((count(parts.part_id_num)-count(parts.cancelled_date))-(count(parts.analysis_Complete_date)))=0) then 100
 when ((count(parts.analysis_Complete_date))=0) then 0
 else
 ((count(parts.analysis_Complete_date)*100)/(count(parts.part_id_num)-
 count(parts.cancelled_date)))
 end as [SC Analysis Completed (%)],

 NULL as [Request Completion Date],
 NULL as [Committed Date],
 NULL as Notes
 from scn_project_details as proj 
 left join scn_part_details as parts on proj.project_id=parts.project_id 
 left join SCN_BU bu on bu.bu_id=proj.bu_id 
 left join dbo.SCN_Product_Name prod on prod.Product_Id=proj.Product_Id 

 where proj.status_id<>12 and (proj.analysis_complete_date between '2014-12-10' and getdate()
 or proj.status_id between 4 and 8) and parts.sc_id is not null

 group by BU.bu_desc,prod.Product_Desc

 union

 select BU.bu_desc as [BU], prod.Product_Desc as [Product Name], proj.project_id as [SC-ID], 
 proj.project_name as [Project Name],usr1.fname+' '+usr1.lname as [Requestor], 
 proj.created_date as [Request Date],left(proj.pm_id,2) as [PM],
 usr2.fname+' '+usr2.lname as [SCE],
 (count(parts.part_id_num)-count(parts.cancelled_date)) as [Total Parts Requested],
 '' as [No. Of Parts Completed Last Week],
 '' as [No. Of Parts Completed This Week],
 count(parts.analysis_Complete_date) as [Total No.Of Parts Completed], 

 case 
 when (((count(parts.part_id_num)-count(parts.cancelled_date))-(count(parts.analysis_Complete_date)))=0) then 100
 when ((count(parts.analysis_Complete_date))=0) then 0
 else
 ((count(parts.analysis_Complete_date)*100)/(count(parts.part_id_num)-  count(parts.cancelled_date)))
 end as [SC Analysis Completed (%)],

 proj.project_completition_date as [Request Completion Date],
 proj.original_commit_date as [Committed Date],
 NULL as Notes
 from scn_project_details as proj 
 left join scn_part_details as parts on proj.project_id=parts.project_id 
 left join SCN_users usr1 on proj.created_by=usr1.[user_id] 
 left join SCN_users usr2 on parts.sc_id=usr2.[user_id] 
 left join SCN_BU bu on bu.bu_id=proj.bu_id 
 left join dbo.SCN_Product_Name prod on prod.Product_Id=proj.Product_Id 

 where proj.status_id<>12 and (proj.analysis_complete_date between '2014-12-10' and getdate()
 or proj.status_id between 4 and 8) and parts.sc_id is not null

 group by BU.bu_desc,prod.Product_Desc,proj.project_id,proj.project_name,usr1.fname+'      '+usr1.lname, proj.created_date,proj.project_completition_date,proj.original_commit_date,
 proj.pm_id,usr2.fname+' '+usr2.lname,proj.analysis_complete_date
```

How can I get the count of parts which are analysed last week and the ones which are done this week.

I want the count for each row in the result, not the total.

```
    (select count(parts1.analysis_Complete_date) from scn_part_details as parts1 
    where parts1.analysis_Complete_date between '2014-12-10' and getdate()
    ) as [No. Of Parts Completed Last Week],

    (select count(parts1.analysis_Complete_date) from scn_part_details as parts1 
    where parts1.analysis_Complete_date between '2014-12-01' and '2014-12-09'
    ) as [No. Of Parts Completed This Week],
```

This code when included in the query gives me the total count in each row. like 125 in all the rows. But I want individual count.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally achieved it by creating a stored procedure and the explanation of it goes as below.

Created a temp table with data and [No. Of Parts Completed Last Week], [No. Of Parts Completed This Week] columns as NULL. And then wrote a update statement to get the count and updated the records. Finally selected the data from the temp table and loaded it in datatable.

```
Create PROCEDURE  [dbo].[SCN_SP_SCE_Weekly_Report]
@startdate as datetime

AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;


declare @date datetime
declare @LastWeekStart datetime
declare @LastWeekEnd datetime
declare @ThisWeekStart datetime
declare @ThisWeekEnd datetime

set @date=(select dateadd(w, -7, @startdate))

set @LastWeekStart=(SELECT  DATEADD(DAY, 1 - DATEPART(WEEKDAY, @date), CAST(@date AS DateTime)))
set @LastWeekEnd=(DATEADD(DAY, 7 - DATEPART(WEEKDAY, @date), CAST(@date AS DateTime)))

set @ThisWeekStart=(SELECT  DATEADD(DAY, 1 - DATEPART(WEEKDAY, @startdate), CAST(@startdate AS DateTime)))
set @ThisWeekEnd=(DATEADD(DAY, 7 - DATEPART(WEEKDAY, @startdate), CAST(@startdate AS DateTime)))

select * into #a from(
select BU.bu_desc as [BU], prod.Product_Desc as [Product Name], NULL as [SC-ID], 
'OVERALL PROJECT STATUS' as [Project Name],'' as [Requestor], NULL as [Request Date],
case
when BU.bu_desc in ('DSM','Synexis','ALD') then 'GW'
when BU.bu_desc in ('Etch','SRP','FEP') then 'MS'
when BU.bu_desc in ('CMP','MDP') then 'RS'
else 'PT'
end as [PM],
'' as [SCE],
(count(parts.part_id_num)-count(parts.cancelled_date)) as [Total Parts Requested],
null as [No. Of Parts Completed Last Week],
null as [No. Of Parts Completed This Week],
count(parts.analysis_Complete_date) as [Total No.Of Parts Completed], 
case 
when (((count(parts.part_id_num)-count(parts.cancelled_date))-(count(parts.analysis_Complete_date)))=0) then 100
when ((count(parts.analysis_Complete_date))=0) then 0
else
((count(parts.analysis_Complete_date)*100)/(count(parts.part_id_num)-count(parts.cancelled_date)))
end as [SC Analysis Completed (%)],NULL as [Requested Completion Date],
NULL as [Committed Date],NULL as Notes,'' as sc_id
from scn_project_details as proj 
left join scn_part_details as parts on proj.project_id=parts.project_id 
left join SCN_BU bu on bu.bu_id=proj.bu_id 
left join dbo.SCN_Product_Name prod on prod.Product_Id=proj.Product_Id 
where proj.status_id<>12 and (proj.analysis_complete_date between @startdate and getdate()
or (proj.status_id >= 4 and proj.status_id < 8)) and parts.sc_id is not null
group by BU.bu_desc,prod.Product_Desc

union

select BU.bu_desc as [BU], prod.Product_Desc as [Product Name], proj.project_id as [SC-ID], 
proj.project_name as [Project Name],usr1.fname+' '+usr1.lname as [Requestor], 
proj.created_date as [Request Date],left(proj.pm_id,2) as [PM],usr2.fname+' '+usr2.lname as     [SCE],
(count(parts.part_id_num)-count(parts.cancelled_date)) as [Total Parts Requested],
null as [No. Of Parts Completed Last Week],
null as [No. Of Parts Completed This Week],
count(parts.analysis_Complete_date) as [Total No.Of Parts Completed], 
case 
when (((count(parts.part_id_num)-count(parts.cancelled_date))-(count(parts.analysis_Complete_date)))=0) then 100
when ((count(parts.analysis_Complete_date))=0) then 0
else
((count(parts.analysis_Complete_date)*100)/(count(parts.part_id_num)-count(parts.cancelled_date)))
end as [SC Analysis Completed (%)],
proj.project_completition_date as [Requested Completion Date],
proj.original_commit_date as [Committed Date],
NULL as Notes,parts.sc_id as sc_id
from scn_project_details as proj 
join scn_part_details as parts on proj.project_id=parts.project_id  and parts.sc_id is not null
left join SCN_users usr1 on proj.created_by=usr1.[user_id] 
left join SCN_users usr2 on parts.sc_id=usr2.[user_id] 
left join SCN_BU bu on bu.bu_id=proj.bu_id 
left join dbo.SCN_Product_Name prod on prod.Product_Id=proj.Product_Id 
where proj.status_id<>12 and (proj.analysis_complete_date between @startdate and getdate()
or (proj.status_id >= 4 and proj.status_id < 8)) and parts.sc_id is not null
group by BU.bu_desc,prod.Product_Desc,proj.project_id,proj.project_name,usr1.fname+'     '+usr1.lname,
proj.created_date,proj.project_completition_date,proj.original_commit_date,
proj.pm_id,usr2.fname+' '+usr2.lname,proj.analysis_complete_date,parts.sc_id ) as t


update a
set a.[No. Of Parts Completed Last Week]=c.cnt
from #a a, (
select count(b.sc_id) as cnt,b.project_id,b.sc_id
from scn_part_details as b
where b.analysis_complete_date between @LastWeekStart and @LastWeekEnd
group by b.project_id,b.sc_id) as c
where a.[SC-ID]=c.project_id
and a.sc_id=c.sc_id

update a
set a.[No. Of Parts Completed This Week]=c.cnt
from #a a, (
select count(b.sc_id) as cnt,b.project_id,b.sc_id
from scn_part_details as b
where b.analysis_complete_date between @ThisWeekStart and @ThisWeekEnd
group by b.project_id,b.sc_id) as c
where a.[SC-ID]=c.project_id
and a.sc_id=c.sc_id

select BU,[Product Name],[SC-ID],[Project Name],Requestor,[Request Date],PM,SCE,
[Total Parts Requested],[No. Of Parts Completed Last Week],[No. Of Parts Completed This Week],
[Total No.Of Parts Completed], [SC Analysis Completed (%)],[Requested Completion Date],
[Committed Date],Notes
from #a

End 

GO
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put the whole query into brackets and use SELECT WHERE to apply additional filter conditions, order by etc.

```
 SELECT x.*  -- choose fields
 FROM (
  -- The whole working query comes here 
 ) as x
 WHERE x.[Request Completion Date]>'20141201' -- filter
```

Better create table valued function or view from your basic query for code re-usability.

Comment: That gives me a filter, but I also want to get [No. Of Parts Completed Last Week] and [No. Of Parts Completed This Week]

Comment: Could you try to format better your SQL code, delete empty lines, indent? It is difficult to read.

Comment: Formatted the code and modified with the latest code.